# IIS 6.0 application pool stop issue

Tags: iis, process, pool, worker

In my IIS log, I found warning level event ID 1013, which says the stop time exceeds expected stop time for worker process of a specific web application.

My question is, how could I know or track from what reason IIS worker process stops? Does this warning level event ID means worker process application pool is stopped or not?

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 2):

If you application is an ASP.NET (2.0 or newer) you can turn on health monitoring which shoudl record details including IIS applciation pool resets.

Useful links

- [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998306.aspx)
- [4GuysFromRolla](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020102851/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/031407-1.aspx)

Comment: Perhaps try using a different error loging technology. I've found the ELMAH technology set to be excellent: http://code.google.com/p/elmah/

Comment: Thanks, does the error message means application pool worker process is actually stopped or not? The more accurate message is -- "A process serving application pool 'DefaultAppPool' exceeded time limits during shut down."

Comment: It sounds like, for some reason, that when the IIS application pool was trying to shut down there was a process lock and it couldn't shut down. IIS app pools normally shut down every 24 hours or after 35,000 requests or when xxxMB is used. You might want to create a new application pool and re-configure it to your needs. This link might help (although it's for IIS7) http://www.asp.net/learn/iis-videos/

Comment: 1. I want to know whether my application pool actually shutdown or not? Any ideas? 2. "IIS app pools normally shut down every 24 hours or after 35,000 requests" -- from default IIS application pool recycle settings, seems there is no 24 hours or 35000 requests settings, please correct me if I am wrong. 3. "when xxxMB is used" -- what do you mean this setting? Which one in IIS manager do you mean?

Comment: Does this picture help? http://blog.fredrikhaglund.se/wp-content/uploads/2008/02/application-pool-recycling.png Goto IIS Manager > Application Pools > [Your App Pool] > Right click and access the "Properties". Good luck